# using reduce to compose an array of cumulative strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I want to return something like this ['4', '42','420'] for a given number: 420

I am using reduce to accumulate the number and using the index to concat the number in the index before. First two iterations are working fine, but in the third one I am having trouble thinking how to deal with the result since it is undefined => `[ '4', '42', '4,42undefined' ]`

Any thoughts?

```html
function createArrayOfTiers(num) {
  const onArray = String(num).split('') 
  onArray.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    if (!index) return curr
    const newAcc = [...acc, acc + curr[index -1]]
    
    return newAcc
  },[])

}
createArrayOfTiers(420)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to collect the incremental digits of a number, I think a clearer approach would be to use `.map` (or `Array.from`) instead: on each iteration, slice the (stringified) number from index 0 to the current index.

```js
function createArrayOfTiers(num) {
  const strNum = String(num);
  return [...strNum].map((_, i) => strNum.slice(0, i + 1));
}
console.log(createArrayOfTiers(420));
```

To fix your existing code, you'll want to access the previous element of the *accumulator*, not the previous element of `curr` (which doesn't really make sense), multiply it by 10, and add to it the digit being iterated over. Also make sure to return the constructed array:

```js
function createArrayOfTiers(num) {
  const onArray = String(num).split('')
  return onArray.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    if (!index) return Number(curr);
    return [...acc, acc[index - 1] * 10 + Number(curr)];
  }, [])
}
console.log(createArrayOfTiers(420));
```

Comment: this answer really inspired me, I actually understood your comment about curr and came up with the solution using my code:

Answer (score 2):

You have the error because you forgot to take first number in the third iteration. You take `acc + curr[index - 1]` but forgot about `acc + curr[index - 2]`.

To fix it you can [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) numbers from first to current and then [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them.

```js
function createArrayOfTiers(num) {
  const onArray = String(num).split("");
  return onArray.reduce((acc, curr, index, arr) => {
    const newAcc = [...acc, arr.slice(0, index + 1).join("")];

    return newAcc;
  }, []);
}
console.log(createArrayOfTiers(420));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function createArrayOfTiers(num) {
  const str = String(num);
  const res = str.split('').reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    acc = [...acc, str.substring(0,index)+curr];
    return acc;
  }, []);
  return res;
}

console.log( createArrayOfTiers(420) );
```

Answer (score 0):

my way

```js
const createArrayOfTiers = arg =>
        [...String(arg)].reduce((r,c,i)=>[...r, (r[i-1]||'')+c],[])

 
console.log('420 -->' ,JSON.stringify( createArrayOfTiers(420) ));
console.log("'elisa' -->" ,JSON.stringify( createArrayOfTiers('elisa') ));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the stringed value by using a closure of a string which stores the value of the last result.

```js
function createArrayOfTiers(num) {
    return Array.from(num.toString(), (s => v => s += +v)(''));
}

console.log(createArrayOfTiers(420));
```

The *reduce* aspect ...

```js
function createArrayOfTiers(num) {
    return [...num.toString()].reduce((r, v) => [...r, (r[r.length - 1] || '') + v], []);
}

console.log(createArrayOfTiers(420));
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to CertainPerformance in this thread I understood that I was trying to access the index of an inexistent array in curr therefore I needed to access the index of the acc value and came up to this solution using an updated version of my code:

```html
function createArrayOfTiers(num) {
  const onArray = String(num).split('') 
  const reducer = onArray.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    if (!index) return [curr]
    const newAcc = [...acc, acc[index -1] + curr]
    return newAcc
  },[])
  return reducer
}

createArrayOfTiers(420)
```

I also transformed curr to an array because in case of only one digit, should return an array as well.

Thanks to all who gave brilliant ideas!!